# Btrfs: Why create a snapshot of a subvolume inside of that subvolume?

Tags: btrfs, snapshot

All the examples I have seen on the Internet are creating a snapshot of a subvolume inside of that subvolume, like below. Is there any reason for that? Why don't create a snapshot outside of that subvolume?

https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-create-and-mount-btrfs-snapshots/

```
# btrfs subvolume snapshot /btrfs/SV1 /btrfs/SV1/SV1-snap
Create a snapshot of '/btrfs/SV1' in '/btrfs/SV1/SV1-snap'
```

https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-create-and-manage-btrfs-snapshots-and-rollbacks-linux-part-2/

```
# btrfs subvolume snapshot /btrfs/sub1 /btrfs/sub1/snapshot
```

I have tested creating two snapshots like that, but the second snapshot included the first snapshot like below. As I keep creating more snapshots it will only look more complicated.

[image]

Why not create snapshots like

```
btrfs subvolume snapshot /btrfs/SV1 /btrfs/SV1-snap1
btrfs subvolume snapshot /btrfs/SV1 /btrfs/SV1-snap2
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really a matter of preference. Personally, I don't create a snapshot of a subvolume inside of the subvolume I'm snapshotting. BTRFS is fine with it, but I find it confusing.

I use the method you suggested: `btrfs subvolume snapshot /btrfs/SV1 /btrfs/SV1-snap1`